# Pygame "No module called pygame.base"

Tags: python, installation, pygame

When I download pygame-1.9.2b8-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame I turn it into zip, take the headers in the pygame-1.9.2b8.data folder into pygame34/include/pygame and I put the other pygame file from the zip in the site-packages folder together with pygame-1.9.2b8.data as any tutorial shows, I always get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/andsa/PycharmProjects/THIS WORKS ANDREAS/Games.py", line 1, in <module> 
    import pygame
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pygame\__init__.py", line 141, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: No module named 'pygame.base'
```

EDIT: I use python 3.4.5, I have tried both python and pygame 64 and 32 bit but i still get this error

Comment: `pygame-1.9.2b8-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl` is for Python 3.6 32-bit. For Python 3.4.5 use `*-cp34-*.whl`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error bugged me for months, what i did was:

1. Uninstalled the package

   `pip3 uninstall pygame`
2. Purged the pip cache

   `pip cache purge`
3. Finally...Reinstalled pygame using pip3

   `pip3 install pygame`

Worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

Use pip3 tool to reinstall the pygame python module:

```
C:\Python373\Scripts>pip3 uninstall pygame
C:\Python373\Scripts>pip3 install pygame
```

Then install it:

```
C:\Python373\Scripts>pip install pygame-menu==2.0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably have python installed for 32-bit. Uninstall and the install the 64-bit version. After that,

> pip3 uninstall pygame

> pip3 install pygame

Answer (score 1):

**SUBLIME TEXT SOLUTION**

OBS: THE REASON MOST GUI FRAMEWORKS DO NOT WORK ON SUBLIME IS BECAUSE OF THIS ONE LITTLE DETAIL HERE

Create a new build system:

1. In Sublime go to >> Tools
2. Tools >> Build System
3. Build System >> New Build System
   [image: PICTURE OF THE TOOLS DROP WINDOW IN SUBLIME TEXT]

DELETE EVERYTHING CONTAINED IN THIS NEW FILE AND ADD THIS PIECE OF CODE:

```
{
    "cmd": ["/usr/local/bin/python3.8", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)"
}
```

[image: FILE CONTAINING THE COMMAND GIVEN ABOVE]
ATTENTION: DO NOT CHANGE THE CURRENT DIRECTORY YOU ARE ON, WHICH IS THE

USER ONE.

4. SAVE IT AS Python3.8.sublime-build
5. In Sublime go to >> Tools
6. Tools >> Build System
7. Mark the Python3.8 you have just created

[image]

Voila!

P.S I Saved mine as 3.7 but it works the same, as long as the code inside the file is 3.8, or whatever version you have on your machine currently.

Answer (score 0):

try usin pip3 install pygames
to install pygames

```
pip3 install pygame
```