# Pygame installation, no module named pygame.base

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, pygame

I am trying to install pygame with the powershell from VS 2019 with python 3.8, I use python3 -m pip install -U pygame --user and it installs pygmae just fine but when I try to run python3 -m pygame.examples.aliens it says no module named pygame.base. I have python 3.6.5 and 3.7 as well in case that has an effect.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 185, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 111, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "C:\Users\jos96\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pygame\__init__.py", line 130, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame.base'
```

Comment: What does `pip freeze` return? Is pygame in there?

Comment: Yes, pygame is in there

Comment: Maybe this post can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49713337/pygame-not-importing-in-python-3-6-4

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't.

Comment: Type `python3 "project path` . What result do you get?

Answer (score 0):

jm96:

1. Check if pygame is in pip3 list:

```
$ -> pip3 list --format=columns | grep -i pygame
pygame                       1.9.6
```

It it doesn't, install it:

```
$ -> python3 -m pip install pygame
```

Note: Keep in mind the following (you have used the user parameter):

```
$ -> man -P cat pip3 | grep -i '\--user'
       --user Install using the user scheme.
```

[What is the purpose of "pip install --user ..."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42988977/what-is-the-purpose-of-pip-install-user)

```
$ ->  pip3 list --format=columns --user | grep -i pygame
pygame            1.9.6
```

2. Check the imported module. You use `from pygame.base import *`. Change it to `from pygame import base`. You can do `from pygame import *` but if you don't need all modules is no necessary.

```
$ -> cat pygame_import.py 
from pygame import base 
import sys

module = 'pygame.base'

if module in sys.modules:
    print("OK")
else:
    print("KO")
```

```
$ -> python3 pygame_import.py 
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
OK
```