# How to use pygame module?

Tags: python, pip, pygame, installation

```
import pygame
import time
import datetime
cup=int(input("please enter how many cups you want to drink in a day: "))
interval=int(input("please enter after how many minutes we should remind you: "))
waterat=time.time() #gives some random time which will help we know the duration
intervalsec=interval*60
if (cup>0):
    if (time.time()-waterat)>intervalsec:
        print("DRINK WATER!!!!!!")
        while (true):
            pygame.mixer.music.load('water.mp3')
            pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
            #plays infinite time
            word=input("enter done if you done drinking water: ")
            if (word.lower=="done"):
                cup=cup-1
                waterat=time.time()
                f=open("drinktime.txt","a")
                f.write(datetime.datetime.now())
                #datetime function is inside datetime module
                break
time.sleep(60)
#program sleep for 60 sec
```

the error I get is-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Nishant/Desktop/practice/water reminder/drink.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "C:\Users\Nishant\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pygame\__init__.py", line 120, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame.base'
```

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not well made. You should have given us more details so we can better answer you. Did you install pygame correctly? What version of Python do you have?

I copied your code and it was interpreted fine. It means you simply did not import pygame properly.

I think you will find answer in this thread:

[Pygame "No module called pygame.base"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40224385/pygame-no-module-called-pygame-base)

Comment: I have python 3.7.3, when I run it using the python IDLE it takes input but doesnt play the music. When I run it using pycharm, it gives that error. I have installed pygame 1.9.6. I tried reinstalling pygame again and again but nothing works/

Comment: Ok I have configured python IDLE so I will stick with this one. I tested your code but it seems it does not work after the "if ((time.time()-waterat)>intervalsec):". It skips all of code in the second if. It might be a problem related to your conditional statement rather than pygame.

Comment: I made another version of this with exact statements but I removed the sound playing part (because of pygame error). It works fine. I dont know how to use pygame properly, but even if my syntax for sound playing part is wrong, it sould print drink water.

Comment: I recommand that you follow a tutorial on pygame. Just google it and have fun creating games!