# Importing Pygame, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame.base'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I’m having trouble importing the **Pygame** module. I installed pygame using the following command in the terminal:

```
pip install pygame
```

When I enter

```
import pygame
```

and run the script, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Pruthvi\.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame

  File "C:\Users\Pruthvi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\pygame\__init__.py", line 130, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame.base'
```

I have tried uninstalling and installing pygame many times. This seems to be a common problem amongst many, yet I haven't found a solution that works on StackOverflow/Reddit.

I'm on **windows** running the latest version of **python (3.8.2)**.

Comment: **Try my MACOS SOLUTION:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40224385/pygame-no-module-called-pygame-base/65183915#65183915

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have more than one instance of python installed on your computer.
and unfortunately when you start python like you did it opens an interpreter of psyder
and when you use pip from the CMD it points to another instance of python installed.

I suggest you to look for every installation of python on you computer and make sure you are installing the package within the right environment.

In order to find the installation path of every `python` and `pip` you can use the command `where python` and `where pip`

Try installing pygame by using the command `C:\Users\Pruthvi\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe -m pip install pygame`

Comment: Hi, the where python command returns the following C:\Users\Pruthvi\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe. I installed pygame in C:\Users\Pruthvi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages which is where I've installed all of my packages so far and have had no problems?

Answer (score 0):

You can check this file exist or not.

C:\Users\Pruthvi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\pygame\base.cp38-win_amd64.pyd

If not, you will got message, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame.base'

And you should reinstall pygame with option --no-cache-dir

Comment: Hi, I reinstalled using **pip install pygame --no-cache-dir**, but the same error occurred?Also, instead of **pygame\base.cp38-win_amd64.pyd** I have **pygame\base.cp38-win32.pyd**

Comment: You have pygame\base.cp38-win32.pyd, but base not found.
Maybe it's version issue. Use pip install pygame --no-cache-dir or pip install xxxxxxxx.whl, You can download wheel here [pygame wheel](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame), select correct version for your python 3.8 and windows 32-bit: pygame‑1.9.6‑cp38‑cp38‑win32.whl

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue before, what fixed it for me was

1. first uninstalling pygame, with pip uninstall pygame
2. then reinstalling it, with pip install pygame

Answer (score 0):

That fixes it for me on python3.8, upgraded my pygame 1.9.4 to 1.9.6